# Are mongodb bulk inserts really increase server perfomance (and faster)?

Tags: performance, mongodb, bulk-insert

Bulk inserts always are faster in client side because of saving round-trips, but at the server-side is there any sensible performance improve?

It seems [the code for bulk inserts](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/db/instance.cpp#L850), just loops over documents and inserts them one-by-one. The 2.6 documentation says "[improved bulk insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#new-write-operation-protocol)" in 2.6, but it seems it's not related to performance.

If there is a real performance improve in bulk-inserts (that is not achievable using threads), what and where the improvements? We know that mongodb does not flush anything on every insert (flushes journal every 100ms, and all files every 30s, by default), so inserting multiple documents in one thread (via bulkinsert) or concurrently by many clients, should not have any effect on disk access. (and probably on index build or write lock)

(This question also is related to "https://stackoverflow.com/q/16533420/326792" but the accepted answer only mentions client-side improvement not server-side)

Comment: Just a note - it's every 60 seconds by default to fsync, not 30

Comment: I think the performance gain is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35112209/2236315